# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_app/urls', but it does exist

Tags: django, django-urls

Error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 134, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/clientDB2/clientDB2/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('main_app/urls')),
  File "/Users/taylordarneille/Code/Django/newenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main_app/urls'
```

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfK86.png)

clientDB2/clientDB2/urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main_app/urls')),
]
```

And yes, I added the app to the list of apps in settings and it ran fine initially.

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I've recreated this project 3 times now and am still having the same issue, but am not having this issue in other django projects. As far as I can tell I have the file structure set up correctly, the code is correct... and I can't find any answers to this question aside from "you forgot to create the app urls.py file". What the heck am I missing/not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a dot `.`:

```py
path('', include('main_app.urls')),
```

It's because it wants to look for it as a python module structure, not standard file based.